# background-image hover css issue

Tags: html, css, transition, mousehover

I am trying to have a simple mouse hover effect on those two pictures but it doesn't work. Could someone help me?

I would need a fade transition when the mouse is over the pictures.
Thank you very much!

```css
* {
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
}

html, body { height: 100%; }

.body {
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.square {
    width: 100vm; height: 100vm; /* For IE9 */
    width: 100vmin;
    height: 100vmin;
    
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: calc((100vh - 100vmin) / 2);
   
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 0;
}

.square:before {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
}

.square:before, .content {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#left-content {
   background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/55/dc/d8/55dcd85ce80e3900ce794efca5fba5ec.jpg'); 
   background-size: cover;
   width:50vmin;
   height: 100vmin;
   float:left;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

#right-content {
   background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/fd/55/82/fd5582332c1fdedbf63afa8e19c961bf.jpg');
   background-size: cover;
   width:50vmin;
   height: 100vmin;
   float:right;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

#left-content:after {
 background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/7a/06/a0/7a06a0f4f472ce6a17f2192123604b48.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 width:50vmin;
 height: 100vmin;
 float:left;
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
#right-content:after {
 background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/2a/14/cc/2a14cc863b23abec6eacb0cefab44451.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 width:50vmin;
 height: 100vmin;
 float:right;
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

#left-content:hover:after {
 opacity:1;
}
#right-content:hover:after {
 opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_intro.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="body">
  <div class="square">
    <div class="content">
 <a href="http://www.google.com"><div id="left-content"></div></a>
 <a href="http://www.yahoo.com"><div id="right-content"></div></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want fade in image on hover ? image over image?

Comment: I have given you very simple answer without writing much css..  you dont need to use pseudo elements :after :before.. just a simple css can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `content:'';` in psuedo-elements to display the element

```css
* {
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
}

html, body { height: 100%; }

.body {
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.square {
    width: 100vm; height: 100vm; /* For IE9 */
    width: 100vmin;
    height: 100vmin;
    
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: calc((100vh - 100vmin) / 2);
   
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 0;
}

.square:before {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
}

.square:before, .content {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#left-content {
   background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/55/dc/d8/55dcd85ce80e3900ce794efca5fba5ec.jpg'); 
   background-size: cover;
   width:50vmin;
   height: 100vmin;
   float:left;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

#right-content {
   background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/fd/55/82/fd5582332c1fdedbf63afa8e19c961bf.jpg');
   background-size: cover;
   width:50vmin;
   height: 100vmin;
   float:right;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

#left-content:after {
 background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/7a/06/a0/7a06a0f4f472ce6a17f2192123604b48.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 width:50vmin;
 height: 100vmin;
 float:left;
 opacity:0;
  content:'';
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
#right-content:after {
 background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/2a/14/cc/2a14cc863b23abec6eacb0cefab44451.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 width:50vmin;
 height: 100vmin;
 float:right;
 opacity:0;
  content:'';
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

#left-content:hover:after {
 opacity:1;
}
#right-content:hover:after {
 opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_intro.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="body">
  <div class="square">
    <div class="content">
 <a href="http://www.google.com"><div id="left-content"></div></a>
 <a href="http://www.yahoo.com"><div id="right-content"></div></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it, you're just missing the `content: ' '` attribute on the ::after and ::before pseudo selector.

```css
* {
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
}

html, body { height: 100%; }

.body {
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.square {
    width: 100vm; height: 100vm; /* For IE9 */
    width: 100vmin;
    height: 100vmin;
    
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: calc((100vh - 100vmin) / 2);
   
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 0;
}

.square:before {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
}

.square:before, .content {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#left-content {
   background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/55/dc/d8/55dcd85ce80e3900ce794efca5fba5ec.jpg'); 
   background-size: cover;
   width:50vmin;
   height: 100vmin;
   float:left;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

#right-content {
   background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/fd/55/82/fd5582332c1fdedbf63afa8e19c961bf.jpg');
   background-size: cover;
   width:50vmin;
   height: 100vmin;
   float:right;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

#left-content:after {
    content: ' ';
 background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/7a/06/a0/7a06a0f4f472ce6a17f2192123604b48.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 width:50vmin;
 height: 100vmin;
 float:left;
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
#right-content:after {
    content: ' ';
 background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/2a/14/cc/2a14cc863b23abec6eacb0cefab44451.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 width:50vmin;
 height: 100vmin;
 float:right;
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

#left-content:hover:after {
 opacity:1;
}
#right-content:hover:after {
 opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_intro.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="body">
  <div class="square">
    <div class="content">
 <a href="http://www.google.com"><div id="left-content"></div></a>
 <a href="http://www.yahoo.com"><div id="right-content"></div></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **You dont need to write a large css for this . A simple :hover and background transition can do the trick.**
>   Here is the updated code:

```css
* {
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
}

html, body { height: 100%; }

.body {
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.square {
    width: 100vm; height: 100vm; /* For IE9 */
    width: 100vmin;
    height: 100vmin;
    
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: calc((100vh - 100vmin) / 2);
   
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 0;
}

.square:before {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
}

.square:before, .content {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#left-content {
   background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/55/dc/d8/55dcd85ce80e3900ce794efca5fba5ec.jpg'); 
   background-size: cover;
   width:50vmin;
   height: 100vmin;
   float:left;
    
    transition: background-image 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: background-image 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: background-image 0.5s;
}

#left-content:hover {
 background-image: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/7a/06/a0/7a06a0f4f472ce6a17f2192123604b48.jpg");
}

#right-content {
   background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/fd/55/82/fd5582332c1fdedbf63afa8e19c961bf.jpg');
   background-size: cover;
   width:50vmin;
   height: 100vmin;
   float:right;
     transition: background-image 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: background-image 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: background-image 0.5s;
}

#right-content:hover {
 background-image: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/2a/14/cc/2a14cc863b23abec6eacb0cefab44451.jpg");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_intro.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="body">
  <div class="square">
    <div class="content">
 <a href="http://www.google.com"><div id="left-content"></div></a>
 <a href="http://www.yahoo.com"><div id="right-content"></div></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

change only below css

```
#left-content:hover {
    opacity:0.2;
}
#right-content:hover {
    opacity:0.2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this:

You just missed `content:'';`

```css
* {
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
}

html, body { height: 100%; }

.body {
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.square {
    width: 100vm; height: 100vm; /* For IE9 */
    width: 100vmin;
    height: 100vmin;
    
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: calc((100vh - 100vmin) / 2);
   
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 0;
}

.square:before {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
}

.square:before, .content {
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#left-content {
   background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/55/dc/d8/55dcd85ce80e3900ce794efca5fba5ec.jpg'); 
   background-size: cover;
   width:50vmin;
   height: 100vmin;
   float:left;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

#right-content {
   background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/fd/55/82/fd5582332c1fdedbf63afa8e19c961bf.jpg');
   background-size: cover;
   width:50vmin;
   height: 100vmin;
   float:right;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

#left-content:after {
  content:"";
 background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/7a/06/a0/7a06a0f4f472ce6a17f2192123604b48.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 width:50vmin;
 height: 100vmin;
 float:left;
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
#right-content:after {
  content:"";
 background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/2a/14/cc/2a14cc863b23abec6eacb0cefab44451.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 width:50vmin;
 height: 100vmin;
 float:right;
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

#left-content:hover:after{
 opacity:1;
}
#right-content:hover:after{
 opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="square">
    <div class="content">
 <a href="http://www.google.com"><div id="left-content"></div></a>
 <a href="http://www.yahoo.com"><div id="right-content"></div></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```